# Render only certain components of VueJs

Tags: vue.js

got an issue trying to integrate a new **Vue** component in an existing **JSF** app.

So far i've created an external Vue app and once builded (i.e. `npm run build`), imported in the app, now im accessing to in this way:

- **head** main.xhtml

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.3.4/dist/vue.global.min.js"/>

<script type="application/javascript" src="../../resources/js/frontend/js/chunk-vendors.[HASH].js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="../../resources/js/frontend/js/app.[HASH].js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../resources/js/frontend/css/app.[HASH].css"/>
```

- **body** targetPage.xhtml

```
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
    const app = Vue.createApp({
        el: '#app',
    });
</script>
```

Which displays correctly but has imported everyting even routing, ecc.

**Is there any way to show only certain components across diffrent pages or have more control of what is shown?**

I've tried to export different components separately or specify the component adding in the script

```
components: {
    MyComponent,
},
```

and in the targeted div `<MyComponent props:... ></MyComponent>` but isn't rendered is shown instead the whole application.

I don't know if it could be even possible to assign components routes values the same as the current page url, it could be a problem if i need two diffrent of those in the same page.

Comment: To reiterate, this is not a JSF related problem. You'd still have had exactly the same problem when using static HTML pages instead of a server side web framework producing HTML pages such as JSF PHP ASP JSP etc. Plain HTML is basically all that gets executed in the client side, there where Vue.js in turn actually runs.

Comment: That's true btw when i render it by serving the Vue app i can choose whether my component is displayed and how, what i'm trying to achieve is to integrate Vue components in a JSF application is possible to show those where i need it @BalusC ? Maybe with only _ad hoc_ scripts?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render the app with root component different from the `<App>`, use

```
function createApp(rootComponent: Component, rootProps?: object): App
```

so,

```
const app = Vue.createApp(MyComponent, { el: '#app' })
```

---

Bud generally you'd use Router, see https://vitesse.netlify.app/ / https://github.com/antfu/vitesse for example

Comment: sorry but can't see how should this work shouldn't i implement `function createApp(rootComponent: Component, rootProps?: object): App
` too? It strangely signals `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after formal parameters`. However i think i can trick it with routes so that's what i'm probably gonna do, what is this **vitesse**?